# Merge Lists or Append Fields in List with unique values

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream, array-merge

```
List A = [
           MyClass(country=BE, userNumber=[12345], cityName = Brussels ),
                  (country= BE , userNumber=[12345], cityName = Bruges ),
                  (country= DE , userNumber=[54645], cityName = Frankfurt )
         ]


List B = [
          MyClass(country=BE, userNumber=[34356], cityName = Brussels ),
                 (country= BE , userNumber=[64325], cityName = Namur )
         ]
```

I have to merge these two list in such a way that the final result will be like

```
   Expected Final List = [
                        MyClass(country=BE, userNumber=[12345,34356], cityName = Brussels ),
                             (country= BE , userNumber=[12345], cityName = Bruges ),
                             (country= DE , userNumber=[54645], cityName = Frankfurt ),
                             (country= BE , userNumber=[64325], cityName = Namur )
            ]
```

Solutions Tried:

- get cityName of both list and did listA contains listB if true then ran a for loop on listB and found same cityName and tried appending the userNumber to listA.

This above solution worked halfway , not sure how efficient will it be. Please help.

Comment: Any chance of posting some code that shows how you obtain `List A` and `List B`?

Comment: List A comes from DB and List B is created newly to append new userNumber into List A and DB.

Comment: Override equals method of POJO then use contains method of ArrayList

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `equals()` and `hashcode()` method in the POJO class with fields `country` and `cityName` .
Then

1. Add all the elements into a list called `finalList`.
2. Iterate each element in the `finalList` and add new elements into a `map`.
3. If duplicate element is found in the map then merge the `userNumber` of the object in the map with duplicate object's. and add back to map.
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 until iteration is complete.
5. Convert `map's` key to `finalList`

Example :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class MyClass{
    private String country;
    private int[] userNumber;
    private String cityName ;
    MyClass(String country,int[] userNumber,String cityName){
        this.country = country;
        this.userNumber = userNumber;
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public int[] getUserNumber() {
        return userNumber;
    }

    public void setUserNumber(int[] userNumber) {
        this.userNumber = userNumber;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;
        return country.equals(myClass.country) &&
                cityName.equals(myClass.cityName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(country, cityName);
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<MyClass> listA = new ArrayList();
        List<MyClass> finalList =new ArrayList();
                listA.add(new MyClass("BE", new int[]{12345},"Brussels"));
        listA.add(new MyClass("BE",new int[]{12345},"Bruges"));
        listA.add(new MyClass("DE",new int[]{54645},"Frankfurt"));
        List<MyClass> listB = new ArrayList();
        listB.add(new MyClass("BE",new int[]{34356},"Brussels"));
        listB.add(new MyClass("BE",new int[]{64325},"Namur"));
        finalList.addAll(listA);
        finalList.addAll(listB);
        HashMap<MyClass,MyClass> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(MyClass myClass : finalList){
            MyClass objInMap = map.get(myClass);
            if(objInMap!=null){
                int[] userNum = IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(objInMap.getUserNumber()),
                        Arrays.stream(myClass.getUserNumber()))
                        .distinct()
                        .toArray();
               objInMap.setUserNumber(userNum);
            }else{
                map.put(myClass,myClass);
            }
        }
        finalList = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
        System.out.println(finalList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Address> first = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Address> second = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Address address : first) {
        int index = second.indexOf(address);
        if(index >= 0){
           first.getUserNumber().addAll(second.get(index).getUserNumber())
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to override equals method and ignore userNumber field in equals method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static <T> T[] concatAll(T[] first, T[]... rest) {
        int totalLength = first.length;
        for (T[] array : rest) {
            totalLength += array.length;
        }
        T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, totalLength);
        int offset = first.length;
        for (T[] array : rest) {
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, offset, array.length);
            offset += array.length;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyClass> listA = new ArrayList();
        List<MyClass> finalList = new ArrayList();
        listA.add(new MyClass("BE", new Integer[]{12345}, "Brussels"));
        listA.add(new MyClass("BE", new Integer[]{12345}, "Bruges"));
        listA.add(new MyClass("DE", new Integer[]{54645}, "Frankfurt"));
        List<MyClass> listB = new ArrayList();
        listB.add(new MyClass("BE", new Integer[]{34356}, "Brussels"));
        listB.add(new MyClass("BE", new Integer[]{64325}, "Namur"));
        finalList.addAll(listA);
        finalList.addAll(listB);
        List<MyClass> merged = new ArrayList<>();
        finalList.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(cl -> (cl.getCountry() + cl.getCityName()), Collectors.toList()))
                .forEach((name, item) -> {
                    item.stream().reduce((a, b) -> new MyClass(a.getCountry(), concatAll(a.getUserNumber(), b.getUserNumber()), a.getCityName())).ifPresent(merged::add);

                });
        System.out.println(merged);
    }
}

class MyClass {
    private String country;
    private Integer[] userNumber;
    private String cityName;

    MyClass(String country, Integer[] userNumber, String cityName) {
        this.country = country;
        this.userNumber = userNumber;
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Integer[] getUserNumber() {
        return userNumber;
    }

    public void setUserNumber(Integer[] userNumber) {
        this.userNumber = userNumber;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;
        return country.equals(myClass.country) &&
                cityName.equals(myClass.cityName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(country, cityName);
    }
Maybe, It is a great way.
```